# Sequelize - Belongs To using a targetKey

Tags: sequelize.js

I am trying to add a reference of cross reference data to one of my transition table. But looks like the query generated by Sequelize is not correct.

Following are the table structures that I am using:

Payment_Type:

[image]

Payment_Dtls:

[image]

Following are my Sequelize model:

Payment Type:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const connection = require('../middleware/sql-connection');

const PaymentType = connection.define('PAYMENT_TYPE', {
    'ID': { type: Sequelize.BIGINT, primaryKey: true },
    'CD': { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNulls: false }
});

module.exports = PaymentType;
```

Payment Details:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const connection = require('../middleware/sql-connection');
const PaymentType = require('./payment-type');

const PaymentDetails = connection.define('PAYMENT_DTLS', {
    'ID': { type: Sequelize.BIGINT, primaryKey: true },
    'PAYMENT_TYPE_ID': { type: Sequelize.BIGINT, allowNull: false },
    'AMOUNT': { type: Sequelize.DECIMAL, allowNull: false },
    'USR_ID': { type: Sequelize.BIGINT, allowNull: false },
    'PAYMENT_DT': { type: Sequelize.DATE, allowNull: false },
    'STS': Sequelize.STRING
});

PaymentDetails.hasOne(PaymentType);
module.exports = PaymentDetails;
```

And when I try to include PaymentType in my PaymentDetails query, the SQL generated does not seem right. My findall method:

```
exports.payment_details__by_current_user = (req, res, next) => {
    PaymentDetails.findAll({
        include: [{ model: PaymentType }]
    })
        .then(requests => {return res.status(200).json(requests);})
        .catch(err => {return res.status(500).json({ message: err });});
};
```

Following is the SQL query getting generated:

```
SELECT ... FROM [PAYMENT_DTLS] AS [PAYMENT_DTLS] LEFT OUTER JOIN [PAYMENT_TYPE] AS [PAYMENT_TYPE] 
ON [PAYMENT_DTLS].[ID] = [PAYMENT_TYPE].[PAYMENTDTLID];
```

Where as I am expecting it to generate:

```
SELECT ... FROM [PAYMENT_DTLS] AS [PAYMENT_DTLS] LEFT OUTER JOIN [PAYMENT_TYPE] AS [PAYMENT_TYPE] 
ON [PAYMENT_DTLS].[PAYMENT_TYPE_ID] = [PAYMENT_TYPE].[ID];
```

I have tried all the following associations, but nothing seems to work:

Option 1:

```
PaymentDetails.hasOne(PaymentType, { foreignKey: 'PAYMENT_TYPE_ID' });
```

Option 2:

```
PaymentType.belongsTo(PaymentDetails, { foreignKey: 'PAYMENT_TYPE_ID' });
PaymentDetails.hasOne(PaymentType,{foreignKey:'ID'});
```

Option 3:

```
PaymentType.belongsTo(PaymentDetails, { foreignKey: 'PAYMENT_TYPE_ID' });
PaymentDetails.hasOne(PaymentType, { foreignKey: 'ID', targetKey: 'PAYMENT_TYPE_ID' });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `belongsTo()` should do what you need:

```
PaymentDetails.belongsTo(PaymentType, {foreignKey: 'PAYMENT_TYPE_ID'});
```

Intuitively, `hasOne()` seems more appropriate ... but I've had a lot of trouble trying to make `hasOne()`use custom keys.

Comment: Yes, I figured out that it has to be belongsTo. And as you said, I am having trouble trying to make hasOne() use custom keys. Appreciate your response.